# Best way to do persistence in C Sharp?

Tags: c#, persistence

I have small number of GUI attribute that i need to save in my application. 
The attribute are simple ( windows size, window color, ext... ) and they need to be store in file ( can be XML or binary ).

I don't sure i know what is the fest and best way to write the code ? 
Is it simple XML or serialization ?

Is there some example ?

Thanks.

Comment: The best way is to vote and accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the value in the web.config file. Here is an example:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="size" value="100" />
```

Edit: Since it looks like its a windows app, an App.config file can be used.

Comment: Somehow I suspect that if the OP is saving window size and color then he isn't talking about a Web app.

Comment: Then he can save it in a App.config file.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use IsolatedStorage to store application runtime settings:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings.Add(<Control.PropertyName>, <Value>);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my preferred way of storing application settings, hope it helps

```
public class Settings
{
    public int WindowWidth { get; set; }

    public int WindowHeight { get; set; }

    public int FullscreenAsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

then in whichever main class is applicable for the type of application:

```
    public Settings Settings { get; set; }

    public void OnOpen()
    {
        if ( !File.Exists( "Settings.xml" ) )
        {
            // init settings
            this.Settings = new Settings()
            {
                FullscreenAsDefault = false,
                WindowHeight = 500,
                WindowWidth = 700
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // load settings
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( Settings ) );
            Settings = xmlSerializer.Deserialize( new FileStream( "Settings.xml", FileMode.Open ) ) as Settings;
        }
    }

    public void OnClose()
    {
        // save settings
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( Settings ) );
        xmlSerializer.Serialize( new FileStream( "Settings.xml", FileMode.Create ), this.Settings );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're stored as properties in a class, such as `Settings` you could serialize this to disk (either binary or xml your choice).

Deserialize this file to get your `Settings` object back when the application starts.  If the file doesn't exist, create a new `Settings` object and serialize the default values.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend XML because it's "human readable" and can be manipulated/view with normal tools.

The really easy method is to use a [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx). The link shows how to define the entity to serialize and how it can be easily serialized. There is also [ISerialiazable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), etc, but why bother when DCS is so easy? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the plain old INI files, for storing non-sensitive values. You could use Nini (http://nini.sourceforge.net/) to read and write to INI files. .NET framework doesn't provide any inbuilt libraries to handle INI files.